# How to send data from Javascript ajax to laravel controller with different directory level

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, laravel-5

I've tried to send data to "plain" php and it works like i expected, however I'm new to laravel and still can't call specific method using js ajax.

I'm trying to send data using ajax post method and call the specific method of laravel controller.

So, my **javascript is outside of my laravel folder**, and **in the same directory "level"** with my html,css and **laravel folder**.

Here is my function in **js** looks like

```
function addNameThroughtLaravelController(){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", "laravel/public/product", false);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send("Name=Jeremy");
}
```

My **routes.php** inside laravel folder looks like this

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => '/', 
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getIndex'
]);

Route::post('laravel/public', 'ProductController@index');

Route::resource('product', 'ProductController@index');
```

and for my **ProductController.php** inside laravel controller folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use DB;

use App\Product;

use resources\views\products;


class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       echo "<script>console.log('index')</script>";
       $product = DB::select('select * from feedback');


        return view('products.index')
          ->with('product',$product);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

       /*$rating = new Product;
       $rating->Name= $request->name;
       $rating->avg=$request->price;
       $rating->save();*/

       $inputs= $request->all();
       $product= Product::create($inputs);

      //return redirect()->route('product.index');
       return redirect()->action('ProductController@index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
         echo "<script>console.log('tes')</script>";
        //'$product= Product::where('idoveralRating',$id)->first();
        $product = Product::find($id);
        echo "<script>console.log('yes')</script>";
        //return $product;
        return view('products.show')
            ->with('product',$product);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *

     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        // $product= Product::all();

        $product= Product::where('idoveralRating', $id)->first();

        return view('products.edit')
            ->with('product',$product);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->Name = $request->Name;
        $product->Avg = $request->Avg;
        $product->save();

        $product = Product::find($id);

        return redirect()->route('product.index');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {

         $product= Product::find($id) ->delete();

        return redirect()->route('product.index');

    }
}
```

There is no error showed , meanwhile i cant figure it out what url should i use in my javascript so i can call to call specific method inside my controller , I've tried to send it to routes.php inside my laravel folder and still didnt work, send it to laravel/public also and still didnt work.

I think the problem is only related to url in javascript post method, because when i tried to access localhost http://localhost/User/laravel/public/product, it print to console index

The output that i expected is clearly that server(localhost) should call the ProductController@index, which should print string index on my console(im using Google chrome for my browser)

**some important thing that might be notice**

**Laravel folder path: C:\xampp\htdocs\User\laravel**

**routes.php path: C:\xampp\htdocs\User\laravel\app\routes.php**

**ProductController.php path: C:\xampp\htdocs\User\laravel\app\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php**

**JS path : C:\xampp\htdocs\User**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's URL on your  `req.open("POST", "laravel/public/product", false);`. try changing it to ` req.open("POST", "http://localhost/User/laravel/public/product", false);`. If apache runs on a different port use port after localhost(i.e: http://localhost:8080...)

Comment: @RavishaHesh tried like you said but it doesnt work

Comment: did you insert "http://" before "localhost..." what do you use to acess laravel project?

Comment: @RavishaHesh tried insert localhost as well,console returns error of  the server responded with a status of 500....what do you mean with access laravel project?sorry newbie

Comment: @RavishaHesh anywy im using xampp apache localhost not php artisan serve

Comment: what adderess do you  type on your browser address bar to get into your home page of laravel project? and if you get a response with status 500, whats the error message?

Comment: @RavishaHesh http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/ and the error message is Internal Server Error

Comment: then you should use `req.open("POST", "localhost/Kevin/laravel/laravel/public", false);`

Comment: first "laravel" for folder name, second because route is "laravel/public"

Comment: @RavishaHesh it returns 404 which is not found

Comment: I assume you are using console to monitor ajax request, what's url the it shows that request was sent to

Comment: And also did you enabled the rewrite module on xampp

Comment: @RavishaHesh http://localhost/Kevin/localhost/Kevin/laravel/laravel/public (ofc its not exist)

Comment: `req.open("POST", "laravel/laravel/public", false);` this should work. I forgot that JS authomatically get current path

Comment: @RavishaHesh it doesnt work,wrong url also(http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/laravel/public), i tried to changeto laravel/public and the url is like we expected http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/ (based on console) but somehow still unable to route it to ProductController@index

Comment: Correct url should be "localhost/Kevin/laravel/laravel/public". as I said before one "laravel for folder name and other because your route is "laravel/public".

Comment: @RavishaHesh hmmm......tried to type on address bar and it shows error 404 also(i get what you mean, but i tried it on address bar)

Comment: try to access http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/laravel/public by clicking on this link. If everything is correct you should get  MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: @RavishaHesh error 404( not found)

Comment: If it's still throws 404, youe laravel project is not configured properly. First make sure that rewrite module is enabled

Comment: @RavishaHesh I've enabled xampp rewrite module, yet still cant work

Comment: Try again after commenting `Route::resource('product', 'ProductController@index');` on your route folder. Just access through browser. Expected output is  MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: @RavishaHesh i tried to access http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/laravel/public after commenting Route::resource('product', 'ProductController@index'); 
still same 404

Comment: Make test route as `Route::get('test/test',  function() { dd('test'); }) ;` try to access it through http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/test/test

Comment: @RavishaHesh tried like u said, but the error still 404, if i use link localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/test/test, it shows(dump) "test"

Comment: Oh stupid me,  I forgot at first place :( very sorry,  of course you have to use public,  try http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/laravel/public

Comment: `req.open("POST", "laravel/public/laravel/public", false);`

Comment: @RavishaHesh no error showed and based on console, the request url is http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/ ...what uri should i use to route to product controller index?
Route::post('what should i put here', 'ProductController')

Comment: You can use any thing you want,  Since it's ProductController,  you can use `Route::post('product',  'ProductController@index);` then url should be http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/product and also most important: remove Route::resource line,  otherwise it'll redirect you to the store method on ProductController

Comment: @RavishaHesh i tried like you said, but it seems like my routes.php didnt call ProductController@index, anway i click my html that related to my js to  call ProductController@index

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: @RavishaHesh not yet, the problem that after i sending it to laravel/public, the route not automaticilly call my ProductController@index, it seems like the post stuck at laravel welcome page

Comment: Remove Route::post line, just leave `Route::resource('product', 'ProductController') ;` and when you call http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/product it should call into store method on ProductController. And also disable VerifyCsrf middleware from laravel/app/http/kernel. php (just comment it)

Comment: @RavishaHesh actually i want to call ProductContoller@index when i clicked my html, which is associated with my js that send request to my laravel routes.php, not directly like you said, plus 1 thing, ProductController redirect to index not store method

Comment: @RavishaHesh tried like you said,still no index printed on console!, which is printed if access the link directly like you said

Comment: What you meant by "no index printed"? Since it's an ajax request it doesn't print anything to your view,  it returns what ever you return from store method

Comment: @RavishaHesh actually i put echo<script>Console.log('index')<script> inside my code, which should be called when i enter the method inside controller......anyway even tho i commend the \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class and changed the post url to laravel/public/laravel/public/product, it still stuck on laravel/public/laravel/public based on console,

Comment: @RavishaHesh i think the problem is the post request successfully ssend, but somehow the route itself didnt work like we expected.I've modified the welcome page of laravel, by adding a console.log, I've tried to click my html and still no log message on console, meanwhile logged on console when i access the laravel/public through localhost

Comment: @RavishaHesh i just want to make sure you get what i meant, Im trying to call  ProductController@index when I clicked my html, which is should be done with my javascript that associated with my html(note html,js and laravel folderare separated each other)

Comment: Then Make a Route as `Route::post('<product/index or anything you want>', 'ProductController@index');` and remove `Route::resource('product', 'ProductController@index');`.  `req.open("POST", "laravel/public/<product/index or anything you want>", false);`. And you have to add ` req.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        alert(req.responseText);
     }
   };`

Comment: @RavishaHesh ok right now im changing the method of routes to get to make it maybe more simple, the progress I've got so far  is I got initiator of localhost based on my console, but somehow the url seems wrong
the.I've changed javascript is $.get("laravel/public","/product") and Route::get('product', 'ProductController@index'); but somehow the url showed in my console is laravel/public? and after the  it proccess  byy initiater it shows laravel/public?/product which is should work if the ? is not there?!!!!! any idea? it is so close i guess

Comment: Why are using ","  between "laravel/public"  and "product"? Just use them together " laravel/public/product"

Comment: @RavishaHesh if i use laravel/public/product the console shows that there is initiator of localhost, meanwhile if is use them separetly , i send get request to server and added extra information along with the request , access laravel/public first then i want to tell the routes that i want route it to productcontroller@index by adding the /product(which the information i send along with request), and IMO localhost should be the initiator of the laravel public execution, because laravel only run on server side(which is localhost) correct me if im wrong :D

Comment: You need to send extra params to routes.php to identify route, When call http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/product it should send you to the ProductController@index

Comment: @RavishaHesh this is what console show to for my last progress the  request url is : http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/?/product the initiator is http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public?/product (which is should be correct if the ? is not there,and productcontroller@index should be called)

Comment: @RavishaHesh what do yyou meant with "extra params"?

Comment: Just use use `$. post('laravel/public/product'). done(function() {alert('done') ;}). error(function()){alert('error') ;}) ;`

Comment: @RavishaHesh Hey dude somehow I've successfully send Get request and post wiht ajax to laravel! only simple thing,  add protected method inside VerifyCsrfToken to check if it is an ajax call.....somehow i've succesfully retrieve the data(code) from server, by do callback data and  all the code that should be run is like expected, however I still unable to run it on server-side, which is the last thing i need to do now! and yeah,u are right using the url like u mentioned before is working like you expected

Comment: @RavishaHesh yup, we cant run laravel on client side(directly on our browser), which is should be run on localhost(in this case is the server)

Comment: @RavishaHesh I made it! i've successfully updated my database from my javascript throught laravel, simple step using RESTful Resource Controllers Verb to make the Controller method work! and you mentioned things that really useful related to get and post!great work and ty !